# In mysql I want to set lower_case_table_names=1 on existing databases to avoid cases-sensitivity issues accross multiple platforms

Tags: mysql

In mysql I want to set lower_case_table_names=1 on existing databases to avoid cases-sensitivity issues accross multiple platforms.

**A)**  `What are the risks ?`( [besides show table issue](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html))

**B)**  After setting lower_case_table_names=1, will I be in position to query databases across 
     multiple platforms consistantly  ?
     `select * from USERS == select * from users`;

**C)** How the triggers + stored procedure + functions + views + events 
    will be affected in this regards. I know lower_case_table_names is only for "TABLE"
names but how about triggers other database objects . Will they remain case-insensitive 
   How about views ?

**D)** Do I need to rename all tables before/after this configuration setting or this  will  do the miracle in one step (i.e lower_case_table_names=1 neutralize table names) ?

**E)**  What will be the exact steps WRT:`mysqd / my.ini` ?

Comment: I strongly suggest leaving `lower_case_table_names` alone. The default setting gives the least problems, as it is design to work OK on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Our servers were Mysql on Windows and we had to change them to Linux. On the new servers we set **lower_case_table_names=1** in **my.cnf** and then copied the schemas with **mysqldump old-server | mysql new-server** (I don't remember if we copied the **mysql** and **information_schema** schemas too, or only the ones with our data, you should try both ways).

Everything is working the same as it was before. Apart from tables we use views, stored procedures and stored functions (but not triggers)